# Continuous form won't show 'new record' while using SQL Server linked tables

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have an Access/VB application that was using Access for its database, but is now using SQL linked tables. My problem is that my continuous forms have quit displaying the 'new record' row. When it was hooked to the Access db, the continuous form would display X amount of rows, and then one additional row, filled in with the database default values, waiting for the user to click 'update'. Now my program is missing this additional row and my users are unable to add a new line of data. I have checked the form properties and the "Allow Additions" setting is set to 'Yes', as well as Allow Edits.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You should check the SQL server permissions to make sure whatever credentials you're using have the rhe right to Insert.

Comment: And just to confirm, you're using linked tables, not adodb recordsets?

Comment: ckuhn203 - I've checked and the credentials do have the rights to insert. Also, yes it's linked tables rather than adodb recordsets

Comment: Another kind of dumb question... You're using MS SQL Server as a back end? I just assumed so.

Comment: Yup! i guess I should have clarified, but it is 2008R2 and Access 2010

Comment: It's a bit over my head, but I submitted a suggested edit to your question that will hopefully get it in front of the right eyes.

Comment: Can you post the details of the connection to SQL Server, i.e. connection string, driver etc.

Comment: @MontyWild - I'm using the ODBC tool and uploading this DSN:

[ODBC]
DRIVER=SQL Server Native Client 10.0
UID=userName
Network=DBMSSOCN
DATABASE=myDataBase
WSID=DSK-068980
APP=Microsoft Office 2010
SERVER=MyServer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are linking to a table without a primary key, or to a view for which MS Access cannot determine the primary key, you can get this effect, as Access can't properly uniquely identify the record to be changed.

The solution to such problems is to add a primary key to your SQL Server table and refresh the link, or if you are linking to a view, to use Access DDL to artificially add a primary key:

```
CREATE INDEX <Index Name>
ON <Linked Table Name> (<Field Name>[, <Field Name>]... )
WITH PRIMARY
```

Comment: This solved my issue! Thank you so much!! I've been trying to figure this out for hours!

Comment: @Greg, would you care to mark my answer as Accepted?